# Как получить метку для поля ввода?

Tags: java

Поделитесь способом получить метку для поля ввода.
В первую очередь интересует сам алгоритм.
Как вариант - по id поля ввода получать содержимое label для этого id, но ведь далеко не все страницы сверстаны с label'ами.
Можно попробовать получать текст рядом с input внутри его родительского элемента:

```
<div class="">
Имя: <input ...>
</div>
```

Но это, опять же, особенности верстки, а нужно максимально универсальное решение.
Подскажите какой-то алгоритм поиска метки для поля. Интересует код для Java, но это некритично, главное сам алгоритм

Comment: можно попробовать отрендерить страницу (например, с помощью webkit) и посмотреть на текст слева (или может справа, всякое бывает, есть иврит/арабский) от нужного элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что если не существует явной привязки текста (по-вашему лейбла) к контроллу, то так же не существует способов однозначно его определить.